# Error in Installation of Drools Guvnor

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss, drools, drools-guvnor

I want to install Drool Guvnor. I have downloaded the .war file (guvnor-distribution-wars-5.4.0-20120413-jboss-eap-5.1.war). Then I have added the war file to eclipse in Tomcat server. Due to this step many files have been uploaded in my work space. What should I do next to do the correct installation of Drools Guvnor?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't they have a readme or guide or something?

Comment: According to the documentation of Drools I have followed those steps only : http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.CR5/drools-guvnor-docs/html/ch11.html#d0e4930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the Tomcat version that is on the zip file that you have downloaded.

Comment: Exactly - as written in the paragraph linked to by the OP: "In the download zip, there's 1 war file per app server version, for example guvnor-5.2.0-jboss-eap-5.1.war for JBoss EAP 5.1."

Comment: I want to  copy the war file into the deploy folder of your application server and then you start that app server. IT is mentioned there. But I am not able to find any deploy folder in my Tomcat

Comment: You should to copy in the webapp folder in Tomcat

Comment: Right now I have kept my guvnor.war file in tomcat/webapps folder. When I restarted my Tomcat Server then runned http://localhost:8080/guvnor/ then its showing me HTTP Status 404 Error.Resource not Found.

Comment: The URL will default to whatever the name of the war folder is. So it will only be /guvnor if the war file in webapps is "guvnor.war".

Comment: Yes Steve , I know that I have kept name of that file guvnor.war but I am not able to overcome the problem of this error. Is there any other file that should be downloaded with this. I am using Tomcat 7 and the file I have downloaded for Drools guvnor is : guvnor-distribution-wars-5.4.0-20120516-jboss-as-7.0.war

Comment: Hi @Niku, download the complete package from http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads and unzip the file. Then, you have a folder with 3 files, you should put the file for Tomcat (you can see that one file has "tomcat" inside its name) inside your webapp folder in Tomcat

Comment: @jjmartinez, Yes this has worked finally. Guvnor File has been deployed.